# WebSphere MQ - Connecting and sending messages to a remote queue

Tags: queue, ibm-mq

I have a .net mq client on my computer and mq websphere queue manager on a remote server.

- **How can I send and recieve messages from a queue that is on the remote computer?**

I get this error: MQRC_HOST_NOT_AVAILABLE

- **How can I connect to the remote queue manager with MQ Explorer on my computer.**

I get:

*Access not permitted. You are not authorized to perform this operation. (AMQ4036)
  Access not permitted. You are not authorized to perform this operation. (AMQ4036)*

==============

How should I configure the server? channel settings? connection settings?
I am able to connect locally when the queue manager is on my computer
but when its on a remote computer it fails because authentication.
I know that I should add my user to the mqm group but the remote computer is **NOT connected by domain**.

thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The reason for MQRC_HOST_NOT_AVAILABLE is because either the host name or the port number you are using are not correct.

To connect to a remote queue manager the following information is required:
Queue manager name: Name (case sensitive) of the queue manager you want to connect to.

Channel name: Name of the channel - of type SVRCONN. You can use SYSTEM.DEF.SVRCONN but it is recommended you create your own SVRCONN channel

Connection name: hostname(port) - Hostname/IP address on which queue manager is running and port at which it is listening, for example remotehost(1414).

You can provide the above information in many ways:
1) Via MQSERVER environment variable. `MQSERVER=<SVRCONN channel name>/TCP/<conn name>`.
 For example `MQSERVER=MY.SVRCONN.CHN/TCP/remotehost(1414)`.
2) Via your application code. See nmqput.cs MQ sample file for more details.
3) Channel definition table.

Comment: I did do this as you stated.
But I think something else is wrong - what should be the TRANSPORT_PROPERTY?

and How do I configure the server side?

Comment: If you plan to use .NET Managed Client mode then TRANSPORT_PROPERTY should be set as MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_MANAGED. By default this property is set as MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_CLIENT which .NET Unmanaged client mode. Other than creating SVRCONN channel and a TCP listener nothing much is needed on the server side.